# Redux does not updates state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <AddPostForm />
      <PostList />
    </main>
  );
}
```

store.js:

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer
  }
})
```

postSlice.js:

```js
const initialState = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Learning Redux Toolkit', content: 'I have heard good things.' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Slices...', content: 'The more I say slice, the more I want pizza.' }
];

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'posts',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    postAdded: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload)
      state.push(action.payload);
    }
  }
});

export const selectAllPosts = state => state.posts;

export const { postAdded } = postsSlice.actions;

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

AddPostForm.js:

```
function AddPostForm() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  function onSubmit() {
    if (title && content) {
      console.log('after if');
      dispatch(postAdded({
        id: nanoid(),
        title,
        content
      }));
      setTitle('');
      setContent('');
    }
  }

  return (
    <section onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <h2>Add New Post</h2>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="title">Post Title:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="content">Content:</label>
        <textarea
          id="content"
          value={content}
          onChange={e => setContent(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Save Post</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  )
}

export default AddPostForm
```

PostList.js:

```
function PostList() {
  const posts = useSelector(selectAllPosts);

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Posts</h2>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <article key={post.id}>
          <h3>{post.title}</h3>
          <p>{post.content.substring(0, 100)}</p>
        </article>
      ))}
    </section>
  )
}

export default PostList
```

The `postAdded` reducer is `push`ing to the state, but after I add a test post (via the form), I dont see the form added. However the `console.log(action.payload)` does shows the object (for example `Object { id: "rTuWGH9pfK-cQvCZecSvt", title: "asd", content: "asd" }`). So why is it not pushing it into the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `button` element has `type="submit"` by default if not specified. The issue here is that the `form` element is submitted and and default form action is not prevented. The result is that the page reloads, e.g. the React app is remounted and all state is the initial state.

Move the `onSubmit` handler to the `form` element and call `preventDefault` on the `onSubmit` event object. Also, it's highly advisable to be explicit with attributes, add `type="submit"` to the `button` element.

```
function AddPostForm() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent form submission, don't reload page

    if (title && content) {
      dispatch(postAdded({ title, content }));
      setTitle('');
      setContent('');
    }
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Add New Post</h2>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}> // <-- onSubmit on form element
        <label htmlFor="title">Post Title:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label htmlFor="content">Content:</label>
        <textarea
          id="content"
          value={content}
          onChange={e => setContent(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit"> // <-- explicit button type
          Save Post
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```

```js
import { createSlice, nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

...

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'posts',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    postAdded: {
      reducer: (state, action) => {
        state.push(action.payload);
      },
      prepare: (payload) => ({
        payload: {
          ...payload,
          id: nanoid();
        },
      })
    },
  },
});
```